# SQL Join with a group by table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Hi I need your help with this:

**Table A** has a line for every time an employee reaches out to the company

| ID | Name | Company | Industry | Segment | Date | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | XYZ | Services | Corp | 2021-03-01 | Peter |
| 2 | John | ABC | Manufacturing | Corp | 2021-03-01 | Peter |
| 3 | Rachel | DEF | Services | MidMarket | 2021-03-05 | Maria |

**Table B** has the monthly target of 'reaches' or'count ID' per Industry and Segment:

| Industry | Segment | Month and Year | Target Companies | Target Count ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manufacturing | Corp | 2021-03-01 | 100 | 15 |
| Manufacturing | MidMarket | 2021-03-01 | 120 | 20 |
| Services | Corp | 2021-03-01 | 80 | 10 |
| Services | MidMarket | 2021-03-01 | 95 | 35 |

Right now I'm joining these two tables to see target vs. actual by month like this:

```
**Temporary Table**
Select
'Industry', 
'Segment', 
LAST_DAY(('Date') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS 'Month and Year',
Count ('ID') as 'a.Count_ID',
Count (Distinct ('Company') as 'a.Count_Company'
From Table A
Group by
1,2
```

```
Select
'a.Industry', 
'a.Segment', 
'a.Month and Year',
'a.Count_ID',
'a.Count_Company',
'b.Target Companies',
'b.Target Count ID'
From temporary table as a Left Join Table B as b
ON 'a.Industry' = 'b.Industry'
AND a.Segment = 'b.Segment'
AND a.Month and Year' = 'b.Month and Year'
```

Now I need to add  Manager and Name of employee in the output too, but the target is not split by employee and manager. Is there a way to join those 2 tables without the group by?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: By default, (almost) anything in inverted commas in MySQL is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate before joining.  Because there can be multiple employees and managers, I would suggest using `group_concat()`:

```
select b.*, a.num_companies, a.num_contacts, a.names, a.managers
from b join
     (select date + (1 - day(date)) day as year_month,
             industry, segment,
             count(distinct company) as num_companies,
             count(*) as num_contacts,
             group_concat(distinct name) as names,
             group_concat(distinct manager) as managers
      from a
      group by year_month, industry, segment
     ) a
     on a.industry = b.industry and a.segment = b.segment and
        a.year_month = b.year_month
```